# JSF updating a composite component

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to update child components of a composite component just by specifying the parent composite ID? E.g. if I have:

```xml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="..." required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:treeTable id="main-tree" ...>
        ...
    </p:treeTable>

</composite:implementation>
```

and to use it somehow like this:

```xml
<my:comp id="composite-component" />

...

<p:ajax update="composite-component" />
```

Is that possible? Right now the only way I see is to specify the child component ID explicitly:

```xml
<p:ajax update="composite-component:main-tree" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done by wrapping  a `<div>` around your composite components implementation and set the div's `id=#{cc.clientId}`:

```html
<html ...>
    <composite:interface>
       ...
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
      <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        ...
      </div>
    </composite:implementation>    
</html>
```

And in the using page:

```html
<my:comp id="composite-component" />
....
<h:commandButton value="Update first name">
   <f:ajax execute="composite-component" render="composite-component">
</h:commandButton>
```

The `<p:ajax>`should work accordingly.